# jquery image following cursor inside div

Tags: jquery, cursor

Is there anyone to prevent this from blinking?
it seems like its happening because it keeps checking to see if the cursor is inside or outside the div?

http://jsfiddle.net/HHKgZ/

Comment: Don't just post a jsfiddle, post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Your code is fine, just move the image inside the div.  The location is confusing the mouseenter/mouseleave event (used in hover): http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/HHKgZ/9/</strike>

```
<div id="plz">
    <img id="image" src="http://images.pictureshunt.com/pics/m/mouse-8557.JPG"/>
</div>
```

**Better solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/HHKgZ/12/

Just put `position: relative;` into your `#plz` element.

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt hide the image when you hover out of the div, just add display:none to #image, technically it should trigger the .hide and .show calls?

Answer (score 0):

Best use the Jquery UI draggable/droppable http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: im using that for other elements but im not trying to drag or drop anything, i just want an image to follow my cursor when im inside a div